# Snowflake connection Error: ' code=35 msg='SSL connect error'

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have an error popping up randomly and frequently when connecting to a Snwoflake Instance via ODBC (Windows-Excel). Drivers are up to date, and other tools connect without an issue using the same driver. Does anyone have an idea of how to fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Detalles: "ODBC: ERROR [HY000] [Snowflake][Snowflake] (4)
REST request for URL https://xxxxxx.us-east-1.snowflakecomputing.com:443/session/v1/login-request?requestId=f2c84d1a-3bfa-450b-95e4-9d41fe2a302e&request_guid=e090e19b-98af-41b7-8f5f-913e02d3b070 failed: CURLerror (curl_easy_perform() failed) - code=35 msg='SSL connect error'.

ERROR [HY000] [Snowflake][Snowflake] (4)
REST request for URL https://xxxxxx.us-east-1.snowflakecomputing.com:443/session/v1/login-request?requestId=f2c84d1a-3bfa-450b-95e4-9d41fe2a302e&request_guid=e090e19b-98af-41b7-8f5f-913e02d3b070 failed: CURLerror (curl_easy_perform() failed) - code=35 msg='SSL connect error'.
"

Comment: Hi you may have to set up  proxy host and port windows as env variables.    This link may help you, https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z000089HPyxSAG/unable-to-connect-to-snowflake-using-odbc-from-a-windows-machine

Comment: Most probably you have a proxy in between and you need to instruct the [driver](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/odbc-parameters.html#connecting-through-a-proxy-server) about it.